# How to get a cell value from devexpres grid

Tags: vb.net, gridview, devexpress

I want to obtaining all cell with same name or value. I want to do that because i want to change their style.

Here it is example of my column and cell values:

```
       INDEX HEROS
        0      BATMAN
        1      SUPERMAN
        2      SPIDERMAN
        3      BATMAN
```

Suppose I have 1000 rows with about 40 cells names BATMAN. How could I get the value BATMAN and how could I change for example their font .

I tried something like this, but it is poor attempt

```
     gridview.GetRowCellValue (BATMAN, HEROS)
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to implement the GridView's `RowCellStyle` event handler. This event is fired for each cell, and the arguments (`RowCellStyleEventArgs`) give you the cell's row, column, and value (amongst other things). If you want to change the formatting of every cell that contains "BATMAN", you would do this:

```
If e.CellValue.ToString() = "BATMAN" Then
   e.Appearance.ForeColor = Color.Yellow
End If
```

You can also change the font using `e.Appearance.Font`, as well as background color, etc. Note that this is just an example, and would fail to format cells containing "Batman", "bATMAN", etc.